# Is there a way I can restructure my createTable in node-postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I have a postgres schema for my node-postgres project, I only have two tables without foreign key created (meetups and users tables). How can I write my code to make every table created with their foreign keys? This is what I have done below, How can I always use await in the table creation. Thank you in advance!

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
});

pool.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected to the db');
});

/**
 * create Database Tables
 */
const createTables = () => {
    const meetupTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        meetups(
            id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            topic VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            location VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            body TEXT NOT NULL,
            happeningOn TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
            Tags TEXT[] NOT NULL,
            meetupImage bytea,
            createdOn TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()
        )``;
    pool.query(meetupTable)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

    const questionTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        questions(
            id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            votes INT REFERENCES votes(no_votes) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
            body TEXT NOT NULL,
            createdOn TIMESTAMPTZ
        )`;
    pool.query(questionTable)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

    const rsvpTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    rsvps(
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        meetupId UUID UNIQUE REFERENCES meetups(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
        userId UUID UNIQUE REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
        response VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()
        )`;
    pool.query(rsvpTable)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

    const userTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
        users(
            id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            userImage bytea,
            firstName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            lastName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            otherName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            userName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            phoneNumber VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            isAdmin VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            createdOn TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()
        )`;
    pool.query(userTable)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

    const votes = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
        votes(
            id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            questionId UUID REFERENCES questions(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
            userId UUID UNIQUE REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
            no_votes INT PRIMARY KEY,
            createdOn TIMESTAMPTZ
        )`;
    pool.query(votes)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });

};

pool.on('remove', () => {
    console.log('client removed');
    process.exit(0);
});


module.exports = {
    createTables
};

require('make-runnable');
```

Comment: Create table and after modify schema by adding foreign keys.BTW: did you think about writing code independent from Database engine? `Knex` is nice library. and he has migration tool: https://knexjs.org/#Migrations

Comment: Yes, I am just learning, I am using the sql query for better understanding, but I will be using sequelize or knex. Thanks very much

Comment: It works by creating table first and alter table to add foreign keys.

Comment: **THIS DID NOT WORK**      `const alterQuestion1 = ALTER TABLE questions
        ADD CONSTRAINT fk_questions_votes FOREIGN KEY (votes) REFERENCES votes (no_votes);
    pool.query(alterQuestion1)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            pool.end();
        });`

Comment: `sequelize `is ORM over `knex` (query builder, also allow to run raw query) I'm sorry, I don't know PostgreSQL enough to help you. Especially without an error message. With this query, who looks on MySQL. A good way to learn is also to analyze magic. Write knex migration, but before running it, run: `set DEBUG=knex:*` to print all generated queries.